# Группировка данных в SQL при подсчете количества строк

Tags: sql, sql-server-2017

Всем привет!
Моя задача - подсчитать количество и избавиться от дублей в запросе.
Допустим, данные такие:
[image: Данные]

Если я пишу
Select COUNT(ID), COUNT(Name), COUNT(Dusability_ID), COUNT(Student_ID), COUNT(Last_Updated_on)
Join ***
from table

выводит
[image: COUNT(]

Мне нужен результат сгрупированный по ID с указанным количеством строк
[image: [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNIv8.png]

Иначе говоря, мне нужны такие данные, но с количеством строк, так как их тысячи
[image: группировка]

Comment: Не верю. `COUNT(Dusability_ID)` не может вернуть 3 на показанных исходных данных. И совершенно неясно, почему две последние колонки в требуемом результате содержат 4.

Comment: результат должен быть такой: ID у всех людей  разные, поэтому их 4. На счет Disability_ID вы правы, их  3,  Student_ID и Last_updated_on нужно вернуть последнее вхождение

Comment: @KelionNoldo используйте ```Count (distinct Student_ID)```

Comment: @KelionNoldo, пожалуйста, предоставьте следующее: (1) DDL и пример вставки данных в T-SQL (2) Пожалуйста, уточните желаемый результат.

Comment: *Student_ID и Last_updated_on нужно вернуть последнее вхождение* Так нужен группированный итог или детальный?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH 
cte AS (SELECT *, 
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Last_Updated_on DESC) rn
        FROM source_table)
SELECT * 
FROM cte 
WHERE rn = 1;
```

или агрегат с COUNT(), если нужен результат с предпоследнего скриншота.

Answer (score -1):

Вроде вот это должно подойти:

```
Select COUNT(Name), COUNT(Dusability_ID), COUNT(Student_ID), COUNT(Last_Updated_on)
FROM table
GROUP BY id
```

Также рассмотрите вариант добавлять DISTINCT внутрь скобок. Например: COUNT(DISTINCT Student_ID)

Comment: К сожалению не работает. Первый запрос хоть и группирует, данные, однако возвращает построчно (мне нужно количество), второй не работает, так как у меня есть переменные с фиксированными данными, например битовый Disability_ID, который в данном случае вернет 2 что не подходит мне